# Consider a game in which two players take turns removing any positive number of pebbles they want from one of two piles of pebbles.

Tags: linear-algebra, induction, game-theory

Consider a game in which two players take turns removing any positive number of pebbles they want from one of two piles of pebbles. The player who removes the last pebble wins the game. Show that if the two piles contain the same number of pebbles initially, then the second player can always guarantee a win.

Comment: So what hve you tried - what is your thinking about this problem?

Answer (score 4):

HINT: The second player can always leave two equal piles for the first player.

Comment: I don't understand. Can't the first player just take all the pebbles and he wins?

Comment: @JuniorSmith: Only if all of the pebbles are in one pile. A player is allowed to take pebbles from only one pile in any given turn, though he need not pick the same pile every time.